# Deploy red5 on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, red5

I need to find  a way to play live video streams on a GUI.
I've made a demo with ffmpeg to red5/oflademo + JWplayer.
This looks good to me so far.
 Thanks RED5 Team!

Now I'm trying to deploy the RED5+oflademo on a tomcat7 server, where the rest of the app resides. 
I've read the RED5War.pdf, but i just can't get this working.

I've built and deployed the oflademo.war from github, then  copied  the oflademo-web.xml in the class folder, but i'm getting a 
 `SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart`

 
Can anyone provide a simple "step by step receipe" to get it work?

BTW, an synoptic of the Red5 architecture could be time-savy.
Many thanks.

Comment: The WAR build is not being maintained at the moment; I suggest that you move your tomcat 7 apps to red5 as its way easier to go that route.

Comment: However, if I needed to add a simple streaming servlet on a jetty like lightweight server, could you instruct me a starting point ? <br> Like the minimum components and configuration?